# How to set filter programmatically in directive

Tags: angularjs

I've got an angular directive that allows numbers to be reformatted based on the responsive break points in bootstrap; so a small device would get a shortened number (1 Mil), a desktop device would get the full output (1,000,000).

Internally this switches between two html versions of the number, what I'd like to do is parameterize the number filter in the template HTML so I can switch it to currency in certain cases.

How can I use the filter argument set through the directive's scope as a dynamic filter parameter?

```
angular.module('myapp').directive("responsiveNumber", ['$log', '$filter', ($log, $filter) => {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            'value': '=',
            'precision': '=',
            'prefix': '=',
            'filter': '='
        },
        template: '<span>{{::prefix}}<span class="responsive-num-full">    {{::value | number:precision}}</span><span class="responsive-num-short" ng-bind-html="::value | shortNumber:precision"></span></span>',
        link: (scope: any, element: any) => {

        }
    };
}]);
```

in use:

```
<responsive-number value="availableFunds" precision="0" prefix="'$'" filter="'currency'"></responsive-number>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//try like this..not sure your stuff achieved or not..but this way u can try
angular.module('myapp').directive("responsiveNumber", ['$log', '$filter', ($log, $filter) => {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        'value': '=',
        'precision': '=',
        'prefix': '=',
        'filter': '='
    },
    template: '<span>{{::prefix}}<span class="responsive-num-full">    {{::value | number:precision}}</span><span class="responsive-num-short" ng-bind-html="::value | shortNumber:precision"></span></span>',
    link: (scope: any, element: any) => {
      $filter('your filter name')(arg1,arg2); //e.g filte,date,currency
    }
};
```

}]);